# What are the negatives of adding a to_str method to Symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

I'm working in a ruby app in which symbols are used in various places where one would usually use strings or enums in other languages (to specify configurations mostly).

So my question is, why should I **not** add a to_str method to symbol?

It seems seems sensible, as it allows implicit conversion between symbol and string. So I can do stuff like this without having to worry about calling :symbol.to_s:

```
File.join(:something, "something_else") # => "something/something_else"
```

The negative is the same as the positive, it implicitly converts symbols to strings, which can be REALLY confusing if it causes an obscure bug, but given how symbols are generally used, I'm not sure if this is a valid concern.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when an object does `respond_to? :to_str`, you expect him to really act like a `String`. This means it should implement **all** of `String`'s methods, so you could potentially break some code relying on this.

`to_s` means that you get a *string representation* of your object, that's why so many objects implement it - but the string you get is far from being 'semantically' equivalent to your object ( an_hash.to_s is far from being a `Hash` ). `:symbol.to_str`'s absence reflects this : a symbol is NOT and MUST NOT be confused with a string in Ruby, because they serve totally different purposes.

You wouldn't think about adding `to_str` to an Int, right ? Yet an Int has a lot of common with a symbol : each one of them is unique. When you have a symbol, you expect it to be *unique and immutable* as well.

Comment: Awesome answer. Do you happen to know about any ruby docs that talk about this? I would love to read up on how to_str is used elsewhere in the language.

Comment: sorry, but i have no specific source on this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to implicitly convert it right? Because doing something like this will automatically coerce it to a string.

```
"#{:something}/something_else"  # "something/something_else"
```

Comment: Right, which is a benefit of adding the method. I guess what I'm trying to find out is whether anyone has a compelling reason to not do this (eg - it causes some crazy bug in rails)

Answer (score 1):

The negative is what you say--at one point, anyway, some core Ruby had different behavior based on symbol/string. I don't know if that's still the case. The threat alone makes me a little twitchy, but I don't have a solid technical reason at this point. I guess the thought of making a symbol more string-like just makes me nervous.